What makes it so that all OneDrive context menu items appear twice in my IContextMenu?
In my application, I'm showing an IContextMenu when a user right-clicks an item. Just like Windows Explorer. The problem is that all OneDrive items are added twice, some with slightly different names. The items in one list have a GUID as verb, the items in the second list don't have a verb, only an id, which is also different from the items in the first list. So it's not possible to filter on duplicate ids/verbs/text.
I've tried getting the IContextMenu using IShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf:
shellFolder.GetUIObjectOf(IntPtr.Zero, pidls.Length, pidls, GetType(IContextMenu).GUID, 0, ptrContextMenu)

And I've tried getting the IContextMenu using SHCreateDefaultContextMenu:
Dim dcm As New DEFCONTEXTMENU With {
    .psf = shellFolder,
    .pidlFolder = folderpidl,
    .cidl = pidls.Count,
    .apidl = pidlsPtr,
    .punkAssociationInfo = IntPtr.Zero,
    .cKeys = 0,
    .aKeys = IntPtr.Zero
}
Functions.SHCreateDefaultContextMenu(dcm, GetType(IContextMenu).GUID, ptrContextMenu)

Both rendering the same results:

Edit: this seems to be a Windows 11 problem. I tested with a clean install of Windows 10 Enterprise (without any additional software) and I didn't have the problem. Then I tested with a clean install of Windows 11 Enterprise and two of the OneDrive items were doubles:

As you can see, they even differ in which items are enabled. One difference between Windows 10 and Windows 11 is that with Windows 11 OneDrive comes pre-installed and with Windows 10 it doesn't and I still had to go and download it. Another difference is that Windows 11 now has IExplorerCommand - maybe that's got something to do with it?
Is anyone else seeing this with their software?
